# React Material UI conditional render table cell color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am current using material ui to display some data in a table. I want to be able to change the color of the row when a string property in the response has information in it.
At the moment I can change the color of the row to a specific color but i cant do it conditional. Can anyone help me thanks.

```
 <TableRow className={classes.row}>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">
                        {row.title}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  row:{
    background:'red'
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your data is coming in, so I will use the typical way in this demo.

```js
  <TableRow className={ String ? classes.row : classes.row2}>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} 
  scope="row" padding="none">
                        {row.title}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   root: {
    width: '100%',
   },
   row:{
    background:'red'
   },

  row2: {

  background: 'pink'
  }
  }));
```

Create a different styling and use a tarnary to  set the className based on a condition.